# Where is the use of Game theory in Generative Adversarial Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

We know that the training of Generative Adversarial Networks is based on Game theory and that a Nash Equilibrium is reached during the training. But when looking on a sample of GAN using tensorflow: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan,

I did not find in the code where Game theory is applied and where the Nash Equilibrium is estimated. 
Could someone show where we used Game theory in this code?

Comment: Game theory is implemented in the sense that the two networks (generator and discriminator) contest each other (Adversarial), but it is not a specific part in the code that you would call "the game theory part"

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And where the Nash Equilibrium is reached?

Comment: It is not always the case that an equilibrium will be reached, but you reach an equilibrium when each participants gain is not at the expense of the other players gain; in the case of GAN when the loss of the discriminator is not reduced at the expense of the generator and v.v.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you write an answer with the corresponding code parts so that I tick it as the right answer for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a theoretical/conceptual answer as there is no explicit part of the code you would call game theory.

Basically, the principles of game theory are implemented as you have two networks, the Generator and the Discriminator, contesting each other (Adversarial part). In a GAN Nash equilibrium is reached when you converge i.e. when the loss of the discriminator does not get reduced at the expense of the generator and v.v. (or more formally when the action of the opponent is not affecting the decision of the player).

In the example provided, you save a model every 15 epochs to ensure that you can capture the model at Nash equilibrium or close enough to it:

```py
    # Save the model every 15 epochs
    if (epoch + 1) % 15 == 0:
      checkpoint.save(file_prefix = checkpoint_prefix)
```

Another way would be to implement some sort of early stopping (or if you use tensorboard track the losses of the two networks to visualize convergence).

This [article](https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/gan-why-it-is-so-hard-to-train-generative-advisory-networks-819a86b3750b) seems to have an extensive explanation of the Nash equilibrium for GANs.